# Intel OneAPI MPI MKL with AMD, is there an AMD flavor?

Tags: cpu, intel, intel-mkl, amd-processor, intel-mpi

I've always happened to use Intel cpus in intel chipset based servers, as such have used Intel's MPI and MKL for the past 20 years that's all I kinda know.  With their OneAPI I only need and use MPI, MKL, and the C and fortran [classic] compilers.

Looking into AMD based servers and clusters, and what crossed my mind is should I still use Intel OneAPI on an AMD EPYC based server/cluster ?  Or does the AMD side of things have their own suite?  Is there a performance hit or problems with AMD + IntelOneAPI versus Intel + IntelOneAPI ?

Is there an AMD MPI and AMD MKL like there is with Intel?  The tags offered here syntactically for this post are "intel-mpi" and "intel-mkl" and intel-oneapi" ?

Comment: Even if it does work, it just reminds me of when MS DOS and PC DOS existed, and PC DOS could run Windows flawlessly, so MS put code in to make it crash for no reason in order to encourage people to switch to their version.

Comment: @easleyfixed: Indeed, Intel has sometimes made their libraries (or even compiler code-gen) choose slow code paths on AMD CPUs.  The joke term is a "cripple AMD" function.  https://www.agner.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6 .  For MKL, one workaround was reportedly to set the environment variable `MKL_DEBUG_CPU_TYPE=5` which worked in some MKL versions.

Comment: AMD has some libraries of low-level functions, they're just not called MKL.  (And aren't drop-in replacements for MKL).  e.g. https://www.amd.com/en/developer/aocl.html and previously ACML (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Core_Math_Library), full BLAS, LAPACK, and FFT, plus some other stuff.  See also [Since MKL is not optimized for AMD hardware, should I use a math library specific to AMD, or would an open-source one be just as good?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1103)

Comment: Good info on the work around.  Interesting, I suspected since MS had done that long ago settings the "standard" for corporate "cooperation" that still plays out in the smartphone market today, with Apple denying the built in Video chat feature from Android to Apple calls.   Obviously companies can do what they want, but this sort of carrot and stick method usually turns me off ffrom a company more than forcing me into its standardizations.  That being said, if there is a work around like you suggest, that might just be the solution in the long run.

Comment: I've never found AMD's libraries to be particularly fast. The MKL_DEBUG_CPU_TYPE=5 trick is outdated, for anything recent do what's listed here https://danieldk.eu/Posts/2020-08-31-MKL-Zen.html Works well with AMD Epyc